# MS Access acImportDelim Specifcation not being used

Tags: vba, import, ms-access-2010, specifications

I'm new to Access VBA, but I have managed to create a specification for my DB to import a txt and this works when being used manually, but fails when used in the following VBA.  When I say fails, I mean it's as if there is no specification used, but the import "works", it just brings in a big mess, but the "correct" data.

```
Private Sub Command2_Click()
    DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, "Specification what I Made", TableName, FilePath & Filename, False
End Sub
```

I've been through everything I can think of, but I'm stuck.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Although it feel a little like I'm talking to myself here, the answer was:

```
DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim,
```

Should have read

```
DoCmd.TransferText acImportFixed,
```

Obviously.